# Is it possible to define a DFA for the language of words having exactly one double letter?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Consider the language $\{ w \in \Sigma^*~|~ w~\text{contains exactly one double letter}~\}$. For example,
$baaba$ has exactly one double letter, but $baaaba$ has two double letters.

Suggested answer for the case where $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$ (even if it's an RE not a DFA): $(\epsilon \cup b)(ab)^*aa(ba)^*(\epsilon \cup b) \cup (\epsilon \cup a)(ba)^*bb(ab)^*(\epsilon \cup a)$.

Comment: You have already put an answer.. so what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you claim to have found a regular expression for the language, you can follow [Thompson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction) to convert that expression into an NFA and then using [subset construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction) to convert that NFA into a DFA.

Answer (score 0):

Start by drawing out individually, the DFAs separated by the union and combine both machines together to get a DFA that the language accepts.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a DFA is that each state of it stands for two kinds of attributes of the strings,

- historical attributes as the string is scanned letter by letter from left to right
- current attributes about the last several letters.

If you want to identify words that contains exactly one double letter by scanning, here are the states and the corresponding attributes.

- $q_0$, empty word
- $q_{a}$, no double letter, ending with $a$.
- $q_{b}$, no double letter, ending with $b$.
- $q_{da}$, has a double letter, ending with $a$.
- $q_{da}$, has a double letter, ending with $b$.
- $q_{dd}$, has two double letters.

Now it should be easy enough to find the transitions between the states given another input letter. Because both history attributes and the last letter are known.

By the way, I recommend strongly that meaningful subscripts be used to tell the attributes associated to the states. Upon seeing $q_{a}$, I know immediately the strings that reaches this state have no double letter and end with $a$. If it is extended with letter $a$, it goes to the state $q_{da}$.